# What does “un-riddable ex-shag“ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In other likeable sociopath news, viewers were thrilled in this week’s episode to see Cersei re-find her love of blood. Only one of those hideous preachy Sparrows have been decapitated by Cersei’s patchwork death machine, The Mountain, but it’s a strong start. Sadly it wasn’t Lancel Lannister, who has proven for Cersei to be the world’s most **un-riddable ex-shag**.

V.V., TRomano Thank you for your help!

Comment: Mysterious ex-lover

Comment: @V.V. **unriddable** is a word I've never heard anyone use in conversation and it's not in my own vocabulary. Is it used as a synonym for "mysterious", as in "Ayres Rock is unriddable"? Is it in the same register as "ex-shag"?  I would take it to refer to something that can't be gotten rid of, that refuses to be gotten rid of, that keeps coming back, something there's no getting rid of. But it seems odd to call something we cannot get rid of *unriddable*.  The passive idea seems to get mangled in the adjective formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret someone being un-riddable to mean they "can't be gotten rid of", and that they are somewhat of a pest.

An "ex-shag" would be an ex-lover.

So an un-riddable ex-shag would be someone who won't leave their former lover alone.